# 2013 Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Server Fault's [third moderator election](https://serverfault.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the two new moderators are:

[image: Michael Hampton] [image: Tom O'Connor]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://serverfault.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://serverfault.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/1584042/0).

Also, please voice your appreciation for hard-working veteran moderator [Iain](https://serverfault.com/users/9517/iain), who is stepping down after just shy of a year and a half.

Comment: Very tempted to close this as NARQ

Answer (score 24):

Thank you all for your support and encouragement.

I separately received an email from Stack Exchange telling me I won the election, and in part it says: "Take it easy—there's no rush, and you don’t need to jump in and wreak havoc on your first day." So I'm looking forward to wreaking havoc tomorrow.

Comment: Tomorrow in EDT or UTC? :)

Comment: @jscott It's best practice to run on UTC, so...

Comment: Congrats, btw. Same for @TomO'Connor.

Comment: Where's my raise and tax cut? Didn't you guys promise that in your campaigns?

Comment: ^ Triple Points Thursdays, yes!

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to say a big 'thank you' to my almost-namesake Iain -- I've not been around here very long, but my perception of his work is that he has been a very moderate moderator, which is exactly what we need.